# Android Spannable - Emoji deletion UTF 16

Tags: android, unicode, android-softkeyboard, emoji, utf-16

I have a problem with the softkeyboard connection and a custom implementation of the emojicon keyboard by ankushsachdeva, with emojione images.

https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

It happens, when I insert some of the newer Emojis in UTF 16 format like this family smileys: http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/2.0//emoji-zwj-sequences.txt

or the smileys with different skin colors. The unicode gets correctly replaced by my ImageSpans.

When I press the my special back button in the emoji keyboard it deletes the full Emoji, by calling the keyevent.

```
    mEmojiView.setOnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener(new EmojiView.OnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEmojiconBackspaceClicked(View v) {
            KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(
                    0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, 0, 0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL);
            send_text.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

But here is the problem:

When I try to press the keyboard backspace button on the default keyboard it deletes char by char and not the whole emoji.

And because the newer smiley consist of multiple chars/unicode surrogates, I have to press the backspace button multiple times and face some strange other smiley combinations.

There are even some strange behaviors when I try to select a emoji by long pressing the EditText, it only selects the first to chars of that longer Emoji, but marks the whole ImageSpan.

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Gabe Sechan for your help.

Here is some code that worked for me. Feel free to add improvements.

Fixing selection in Custom EditText:

```
LinkedList<EmojiData.EmojiTupel> mEmojis = new LinkedList<>();
boolean fromReselecting = false;
@Override
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    //Log.d("Selection changed", selStart + " " + selEnd + " length: "  + getText().length());
    if(!fromReselecting && selStart != selEnd){
        EmojiData.EmojiTupel toFix = inBetweenEmoji(selStart, selEnd);
        if(toFix != null){
                    fromReselecting = true;
                    setSelection(toFix.start, toFix.end);
        }
    }
    else{
        fromReselecting = false;
    }
}

private EmojiData.EmojiTupel inBetweenEmoji(int selStart, int selEnd){
    if(mEmojis == null){
        return null;
    }
    for (EmojiData.EmojiTupel tupel: mEmojis) {
        if((tupel.start < selStart && selEnd <= tupel.end) ||
                (tupel.start <= selStart && selEnd < tupel.end)
                ){
            //Log.d("InBetween ", "Selection: " + selStart + " " + selEnd + " Emoji: " + tupel.start + " "+ tupel.end );
            return tupel;
        }
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
            mEmojis = EmojiUtils.insertEmojis(getContext(), getText(), mEmojiconSize);
}
```

Also in there the Custom InputConnection that uses KeyEvents when Text should be deleted. Works fine with multiple Emojis, because selection is fixed.

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    return new EmojiInputConnection(super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs),
            true);
}

private class EmojiInputConnection extends InputConnectionWrapper {

    public EmojiInputConnection(InputConnection target, boolean mutable) {
        super(target, mutable);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int beforeLength, int afterLength) {
        if (beforeLength == 1 && afterLength == 0) {
            return sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL))
                    && sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
        } else{
            int cursorPos = getSelectionStart();
            int cursorEnd = getSelectionEnd();
            if(cursorEnd == cursorPos && beforeLength == 2 && afterLength == 0){
                return sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL))
                        && sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
            }
        }

        return super.deleteSurroundingText(beforeLength, afterLength);
    }

}
```

Where EmojiTupel is a wrapper for indexes in the String from another class.

```
public static class EmojiTupel{
                public int start, end;
                public EmojiTupel(int start, int end){
                        this.start = start;
                        this.end = end;
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of how softkeyboards work.  Very few of them use key events.  They're more likely to use deleteSurroundingText for a delete press.  What you'd need to do is override the inputConnection for your view, and override deleteSurrounding text such that if there's an emoji in the deleted area, it deletes the entire emoji and not just the single character.